# How can I get product details when the div container has itemscope using Python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to web scrape a **page under login** which has

```
<div class="price-container" itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer"> 
<span class="price-label">Τιμή:</span> 
<span class="final-price"><span itemprop="price">935,96 €</span> </span> 
<meta itemprop="currency" content="EUR"> 
<meta itemprop="availability" content="in_stock"> 
</div>
```

and I cannot get the actual final price under span which is calculated from a javascript

if I use

```
price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'final-price'})
```

I get the 935,96 and not the one I see on the page

```
itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer"
```

is responsible for hiding the actual prices?

How can I get the actual final price

[image]

You will see that there is a price of 922,24 discounted with a 1.5% of 935,96 and a extra discount of 22% calculated with javascript but how to get the 721,08?

Comment: 935,96 is the same value as in your html so I am not clear where the discrepancy lies.

Comment: They apply a discount so the page which it is displayed is the discounted price which I cannot get, I get only the initial price, it has to do with microdata?

Comment: Have you searched the html for 721.08 in the output soup?

Comment: yes there isn't anywhere

Comment: 1) can you retrieve the actual and the percentage so as to do the calc yourself? 2) If you refresh the page and use the network tab can the discount value be found in any other traffic?

Comment: for the 1) no I get none even for discount percentage its hidden too..for 2) I reloaded I clicked Network and JS and open the pricing.js which calculate prices?

Comment: You could certainly see if you can use the js script. Have you done Ctrl + F in the network tab to search for either the percentage or reduced value? Percentage may be as decimal.

Comment: No does not exists a float decimal only variables like var price = parseFloat(item.Price); var offer = parseFloat(item.Price2); var weboffer = parseFloat(item.Price1)

Comment: whats the url of the site?